# How can I convert public/extended public hdkey (hierarchical deterministic) into solana public key

Tags: private-key, publickey

I have a xpubkey (public/extended public key) generate from HD Key (hierarchical deterministic key) and I want to convert this key to Solana Public Key but no luck

As my purpose, I want to secure my hd private key, so the main target is converted hd public key into Solana public key.

```
import * as solanaWeb3 from '@solana/web3.js'
import base58 from 'bs58'
import hdkey from 'hdkey'

const {
  Keypair,
  PublicKey,
} = solanaWeb3;

const extendPrivateKey = `xprvxxxxxxxxx` //* Example of extend private key
const extendPublicKey = `xpubxxxxxxxxx` //* Example of extend public key

const masterseed = hdkey.fromExtendedKey(extendPrivateKey)
const path = `m/1/1/1/1`

const nodeData = masterseed.derive(path)
const { publicKey, privateKey } = nodeData

const keyPairSol = Keypair.fromSeed(privateKey)
const publicKeySol = keyPairSol.publicKey.toBase58()
```

By this way, I can convert the extendPrivateKey into solana public key
But I couldn't find the way that only use the public key (xpub) of hdkey to convert it into solana public key

Are there any ways to do this ?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out or are you still searching for an answer to this question @Doan Thanh Ha?